# Strange shadow on my object

Tags: camera, shadows

I am beginner in the blender and i have a problem with a strange shadows on my objects.
It is hard to explain,so lets discuss an example.
I have a group of the flat (or almost flat) buildings (please check the second picture), but i have shadows that looks like shadows from the volume buildings.For example where is a shadow of the ladder structure on the building, but it has a flat structure.
Thats why my picture looks weird : blender adds random shadows and distorts my picture.Is it possible to fix that?

[image: Picture 1: group of buildings]

[image: Picture 2: normal building]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps tweak the Clip Start and End values in the N panel > View?